# Naming columns in a table

Tags: tables, column-headers, naming

I suspect that part of my problem is that I am not a native english speaker but here it is. I have a table with column header labels. One of these columns contains the "number of messages received". Another, the "number of messages archived", etc. How should I label these columns ?

option A: "messages received", "messages archived", etc.
option B: "received messages", "archived messages", etc.

Mathieu

Comment: I assume the table isn't solely describing messages, so you couldn't just have "Received" and "Archived" as column headings?

Comment: yes, it is not solely describing messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend going with the first, and placing the stress on the nouns. This is more natural for English speakers, from your name I suspect you might be French-speaking and inclined to reverse the order of adjectives and nouns?

For guidance, check out Google Images with some samples, you will see clearly the stress on nouns:

https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1489&bih=722&q=table+data&oq=table+data&gs_l=img.3..0l6j0i5l4.607.1854.0.2062.10.10.0.0.0.0.125.930.6j4.10.0....0...1ac.1.43.img..1.9.823.UlfeoeJ32ek

It's also the use of the participle - by placing it before the object the reader is looking instinctively for a subject. By placing the noun first, the missing subject does not cry out for attention in the same way.

Comment: yes, I am french, but, no, I was leaning towards the first (the UI is currently using the second but it bothers me and I can't tell why)